# C++ heap corrupt

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int arr[] = { 5, 3, 6 };
    Vect v(a, arr);
    v.add(1);
    v.add(2);
    v.add(3);
    v.add(4);
    return 0;
}
```

`Vect` class:

```
int n;
int* ptr = new int[n];
```

Constructor:

```
Vect(int nInit, int arr[])
{
    n = nInit;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = tab[i];
    }
}
```

add method in `Vect` class:

```
 void add(int value)
 {
    n += 1;
    ptr[n-1] = value;
 }
```

I'm getting the error `Program.exe has triggered a breakpoint.` at 
`msvcr120d.dll!_heap_alloc_base(unsigned int size) Line 58`.
I've also tried using `memcpy`.

The interesting thing is that when I only call `add` once or twice, or when sending only one `int` in the `arr` array, everything is okay.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Where are you initializing `ptr`? Is `n` initialized at that point? Besides that you seem to be accessing the array out of bounds, even if `ptr` were correctly initialized.

Comment: in what method is int n;
int* ptr = new int[n]; written since it is not a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Source of Problem is:

```
void add(int value)
{
   n += 1;
   ptr[n-1] = value; // Danger !!!!
}
```

You're creating a memory of size **'n'** using **new**

```
  int* ptr = new int[n];
```

But in the function **void add(int value)** you're trying to store a numbers in the location which is out of the allocated memory (problem).

**Solution 1:**

If you already know what is the maximum numbers you want to store in the memory then allocate that much of memory first using **new** and then do any number of storing within that allocated size.

**Solution 2:**

If you want to store more number than what you allocated initially then allocate a new memory using the below function **(Note:** copy the old content to new memory and delete the old/new allocated memory after use for avoiding memory leaks.**)**

```
void  Vect::resize(int newSize ) {   
      int* newArr = new int[newSize];
      memcpy( newArr, ptr, n * sizeof(int) );
      n = newSize;
      delete [] ptr;
      ptr = newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether n is less than what you have used while allocating memory.

```
void add(int value)
 {
    // add logic to check your n is less than used while allocating.
    //if(n < N) 
    n += 1;
    ptr[n-1] = value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method `add` you increase `n`. But `n` is merely an indicator of how much memory you have allocated in a past (in ctor). So what you are doing now is just increase the indicator and pretend the array now is larger. But you haven't enlarged the array. So you are writing new value OUTSIDE of the array, hence the exception.

If you want to add element to your array you have to:

- allocate second array, larger than the first one
- copy contents of fist into second (this leaves last cell of second untouched)
- swap those arrays, so now the `ptr` will point to the new one
- `delete` the old array
- finally assign the new int into last cell of the second

/edit: same goes for the constructor. If I understand your code correctly, and the `n` indicates size of the array, you can NEVER touch the `n` without `ptr = new int[n];` somewhere in the given method.

Comment: All good points but it looks like he isn’t even allocating the array in the ctor but rather he is trying to do it in the class…